# preg_replace int, decimal, negative numbers

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

replace ALL numbers. negative, positive, separated by comma, point, etc

I have

```
  $txt = "car -12 and dog 3.1416 and cat 98 and 4,12 and flowers = 0.1 and -75";
```

I like

```
$txt = "car NUM and dog NUM and cat NUM and NUM and flowers = NUM and NUM";
```

Please help

Comment: [`$repl = preg_replace('/[+-]?\d+(?:[.,]\d+)?/', 'NUM', $str);`](https://regex101.com/r/USCCMC/1)

Comment: Did that work for you?

Answer (score 1):

```
$a = preg_replace('/(-)?[0-9]+(.)?[0-9]+/','NUM',$txt);
```

Comment: Please add some explenation to your answer.

Comment: parameter 1 is the regex to match all numbers ,then use parameter 2 to replace it

Comment: This will replace `123X456` with `NUM`

Answer (score 0):

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/0PaqH))

```
$txt = "car -12 and dog 3.1416 and cat 98 and 4,12 and flowers = 0.1 and -75";
echo "EXPECT: car NUM and dog NUM and cat NUM and NUM and flowers = NUM and NUM\n";
echo "OUTPUT: ",preg_replace('~-?\d*[,.]?\d+~','NUM',$txt);
```

Output:

```
EXPECT: car NUM and dog NUM and cat NUM and NUM and flowers = NUM and NUM
OUTPUT: car NUM and dog NUM and cat NUM and NUM and flowers = NUM and NUM
```

Breakdown:

```
~      #pattern delimiter
-?     #match zero or one hyphen
\d*    #match zero or more digits
[,.]?  #match zero or one character in list: comma or dot
\d+    #match one or more digits
~      #pattern delimiter
```

If this pattern does not perform as desired on all of your input strings, please update your question to include these troublesome strings and leave me a comment and I'll update my answer.

*notes:

- I don't use any capture groups because capture groups cost more "steps" (slow down the regex engine).
- A `.` inside of a character class `[.]` does not need to be escaped to be treated literally.  Using `.` outside of a character class will need to be escaped in some manner, otherwise it will be treated as "any non-newline character".